# React-router updating url but component not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have an application in React where I have a small form that is to be filled and then when the user clicks submit button it should take him to another page completely. While I have only designed the visual part and nothing functional is programmed in the app, I tried setting up the Routers using react-router v4.3.1. I am new to react-router, what I want is the previous content to unmount completely and a new Component to be loaded. This is my code.
Here I have my App.js which contains Routing.js where I have set up my router

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Routing />
        <Brand />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is Routing.js

```
const Routing = (props) => {
    return (<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch location={props.location}>
                <Route path="/" exact component={HomeJumbotron} />
                <Route path="/section1" component={SecondPage} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>);
}
```

Here's HomeJumbotron which houses component `PaymentForm` where I have the button that when pressed, should unmount `HomeJumbotron` and mount `SecondPage`

```
class HomeJumbotron extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Jumbotron className="main">
        <div className="container">
          <Header />
          <PaymentForm />
        </div>
      </Jumbotron>
    );
  }
}

class PaymentForm extends Component {
  handleValidSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleClick() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://e27c15ee-bc16-4709-902a-783a1f517b79.mock.pstmn.io/demo?uId=001"
      )
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AvForm onValidSubmit={this.handleValidSubmit}>
        <Ref />
        <Amount />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Link to="/section1">
            <div>
              <Button className="wide" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                Pay
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AvForm>
    );
  }
}
```

Now what happens is when I am pressing the button, the url changes but the new Component is not rendering, basically nothing changes! Now with this if I refresh the page, it works, which makes sense because the url has been updated. But I can't always refresh the page to make the new contnent show up! I think I might be blocking update but then I'm not getting where I have to pass the location? I tried many things but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only have a `BrowserRouter` component at the top of your app like you already have. Remove the one around your `Link` and it will work as expected.

```
class PaymentForm extends Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <AvForm onValidSubmit={this.handleValidSubmit}>
        <Ref />
        <Amount />
        <Link to="/section1">
          <div>
            <Button className="wide" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
              Pay
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </AvForm>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like magic!! So I think I was nesting BrowserRouter which was creating the issue!! Thanks a tonn!

Comment: Sorry I am kinda new to stackoverflow. Accepted it! :)